# Custom View - Move Views into nested Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom View, which shows a Card with follwing Contents:

- TextView (Caption)
- TextView (Description)
- LinearLayout (innerLayout)

So i just extended a LinearLayout and inflated my Layout file with it:

```
public class FrageContainerView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView objTextViewCaption;
    private TextView objTextViewDescription;

    private String caption;
    private String description;

    private LinearLayout objLayoutInner;

    public FrageContainerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.options_frageContainerView, 0, 0);

        caption = a.getString(R.styleable.options_frageContainerView_caption);
        description = a.getString(R.styleable.options_frageContainerView_description);

        a.recycle();

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragecontainer, this, true);

        objLayoutInner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_inner);
        objTextViewCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_caption);
        objTextViewDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_description);

        objTextViewCaption.setText(caption);
        objTextViewDescription.setText(description);
    }
```

A user which uses my custom View should be able to add his own Components preferably inside the XML like this:

```
    <FrageContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        custom:caption="Hallo"
        custom:description="LOLOLOL"
        android:background="#FF00FF00">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="sdsdfsdf"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="sdsdfsdf"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="sdsdfsdf"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="sdsdfsdf"/>

    </FrageContainerView>
```

The current State is, that the defined EditText's are inflated inside my custom View. I want the EditTexts in my Example to be added to the InnerLayout instead to append them to Custom View.

What's the best approach to do this?

Comment: "I have hard time explaining what I want to do". Yes, your question has had lots of views, but no answers, because it is confusing and unclear. Explain more.

Comment: @Sound Conception I updated my Question :)

Comment: Aha! You don't mean 'user' in the normal sense (as in someone using your app) do you. You actually mean another Software Developer using your class, right?

Comment: Yes, User of the custom component (but probably Just me :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of this problem is how to add child Views to a `GroupView` that is itself a child of the custom layout.

This is relatively straightforward programmatically, but more of an issue in XML.

Androids `LayoutInflater` logically interprets the nested levels in an XML file and builds the same structure in the hierarchy of Views it creates.
Your example XML defines 4 `EditText` Views as first tier children of `FrageContainerView`, but you want them to be created as second tier children of `FrageContainerView` sitting inside your `LinearLayout`. This would mean changing Androids `LayoutInflater` which is a core component of the whole Android system.

To do this programmatically you could do something like the following:

```
public class FrageContainerView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView objTextViewCaption;
    private TextView objTextViewDescription;

    private String caption;
    private String description;

    private LinearLayout objLayoutInner;

    public FrageContainerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public FrageContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        // Create your 3 predefined first tier children

        // Create the Caption View
        objTextViewCaption = new TextView(context);
        // You can add your new Views to this LinearLayout
        this.addView(objTextViewCaption)

        // Create the Description View
        objTextViewDescription = new TextView(context);
        // You can also provide LayoutParams when you add any of your new Views if you want to
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.addView(objTextViewDescription, params);

        // Create your inner LinearLayout
        objLayoutInner = new LinearLayout(context);
        objLayoutInner.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        // Add it
        this.addView(objLayoutInner);

        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.options_frageContainerView, 0, 0);

        caption = a.getString(R.styleable.options_frageContainerView_caption);
        description = a.getString(R.styleable.options_frageContainerView_description);

        a.recycle();

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

/** 
 * Oops! Only just spotted you're inflating your three predefined views 
 * here. It's fine to do this instead of programmatically adding them as I
 * have above. Obviously they should only be added once, so I've commented out
 * your version for the moment.
 **/

//        LayoutInflater inflater =
//                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragecontainer, this, true);
//
//        objLayoutInner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_inner);
//        objTextViewCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_caption);
//        objTextViewDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_description);

        objTextViewCaption.setText(caption);
        objTextViewDescription.setText(description);
    }
}

/** Public method for adding new views to the inner LinearLayout **/
public void addInnerView(View view) {
    objLayoutInner.addView(view);

}

/** Public method for adding new views to the inner LinearLayout with LayoutParams **/
public void addInnerView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
    objLayoutInner.addView(view, params);
}
```

You would use this in your code with something like the following:

```
FrageContainerView fragContainerView = (FrageContainerView) findViewById(R.id.my_frag_container_view);

TextView newView = new TextView(context);
newView.setText("whatever");

fragContainerView.addInnerView(newView);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other thing you could do is

1) Cache all current children and remove them all

`ArrayList<View> nestedViews = ViewUtil.getAllChildren(this); removeAllViews();`

2) Inflate the layout you have which already contains things

`View myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout_with_stuff, null);`

3) Add the cached views to the newly inflated layout and add it to the root back

```
    for (View view : nestedViews) {
        myLayout.<ViewGroup>findViewById(R.id.contentLayout).addView(view);
    }

    addView(myLayout);
```